# matching and unmatched lines from two large data sets

Tags: python, regex, stream, match, python-2.4

I am using Python 2.4 and am pretty new at Python, programming in general and regular expressions.  I have a large module that currently outputs two separate streams(or datasets/files) of lines, stream A and stream B.  I am trying to compare stream A to stream B to see if any strings in stream B can be matched within any lines of stream A.  I want to return all matching contents and all unmatched contents as two separate objects.  Please **see my issue, in bold,** below.  Does anyone know how I can overcome this problem or have a best-practices recommendation?

So far, I have turned stream B ("realtimes") into a list ("regexes") and converted that list into a group of regular expressions ("combined"), using this code

*please note I am not including all of the code in my module, just the part that I am stuck on*:

```
regex = re.compile(r'.*\[(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{6})\].*')
optsymbx = re.compile(r'\[(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{6})\][\s]+(trade),(S|B),(\d{1,}),(\w+)[\s]+([0-9A-Z]+),(\d+\.\d+)')
regexes = []

def realtimes():
    for x in realtrades():
        x = str(x)
        m = re.match(regex,x)
        if m:
            #regexes.append(str(m.groups()))
            yield str(m.groups())

#make contents of realtimes into group of regular expressions     
f = open(logfile,'r')
for x in realtimes():
    regexes.append(x)
combined = "(" + ")|(".join(regexes) + ")"
```

Then I look into stream A (lines in f), and check each line against "combined" and one additional regex criteria ("optsymbx"), to see if there is a match or not, as follows:

```
# checking if any lines in the logfile match "optsymbx" and any regular expressions wihtin "combined"
f = open(logfile,'r')
for line in f:
    m = re.match(combined,line)
    mopt = re.match(optsymbx,line)
    if not m:
        if mopt:
            print line
```

**The issue is that stream A and B are very large.  Stream A contains over 100,000 lines and Stream B has several thousand.  So, when I turn the contents of Stream B into a group of regular expressions ("combined"), it exceeds a capacity of 100 named groups and I get an error:**  Also, I tested and know this works when I reduce the size of the contents of Stream B into less than 100 named groups.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "badtrades.py", line 121, in ?
    m = re.match(combined,line)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/sre.py", line 129, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/sre.py", line 225, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/sre_compile.py", line 506, in compile
    raise AssertionError(
AssertionError: sorry, but this version only supports 100 named groups
```

sample data from combined (derived from stream B):

```
    ["('09:50:31.458370',)", **"('09:50:31.458370',)"**, "('09:50:48.343785',)", "('09:50:48.449219',)", "('09:50:48.449219',)", "('09:50:48.449219',)", "('09:50:48.449219',)", "('09:51:01.986971',)", "('09:51:01.986971',)", "('09:51:01.986971',)", "('09:51:34.543147',)", "('09:52:14.688349',)", "('09:52:14.688349',)", "('09:52:14.688349',)", "('09:52:14.688349',)", "('09:52:19.700134',)", "('09:53:06.696156',)", "('09:53:06.696156',)", "('09:53:06.696156',)", "('09:53:06.696156',)", "('09:53:06.696156',)", "('09:53:06.696156',)", "('09:53:06.696156',)", "('09:53:06.696156',)", "('09:54:39.295261',)", "('09:54:39.295261',)", "('09:54:44.883143',)", "('09:54:44.883143',)", "('09:54:44.883143',)", "('09:54:44.883143',)", "('09:55:17.750226',)", "('09:55:17.750226',)", "('09:55:17.750226',)", "('09:55:17.750226',)", "('09:55:17.750226',)", "('09:55:17.750226',)", "('09:55:17.750226',)", "('09:55:17.750226',)", "('09:55:17.750226',)", "('09:55:19.767099',)", "('09:55:26.750094',)", "('09:55:26.750094',)", "('09:55:29.195194',)", "('09:55:29.195194',)", "('09:55:29.195194',)", "('09:55:29.195194',)", "('09:55:29.195194',)", "('09:55:29.722747',)", "('09:56:38.809658',)", "('09:56:38.809658',)", "('09:57:38.444653',)", "('09:57:38.444653',)", "('09:57:38.444653',)", "('09:57:38.444653',)", "('09:57:38.444653',)", "('09:57:38.444653',)", "('09:57:38.444653',)", "('09:57:38.444653',)", "('09:57:38.444653',)", "('09:57:38.444653',)", "('09:57:38.444653',)", "('09:57:38.444653',)", "('09:57:38.444653',)", "('09:57:38.444653',)", "('09:57:38.444653',)", "('09:58:37.573746',)", "('09:58:37.573746',)", "('09:58:37.573746',)", "('09:59:02.185210',)", "('09:59:09.245981',)", "('09:59:33.619633',)", "('09:59:33.619633',)", "('09:59:33.619633',)", "('09:59:33.619633',)"]
```

sample data from logfile (stream A):

```
[09:49:52.515951] T,AAPL  130518C00450000,1,32.05
[09:49:53.568816] T,AAPL  130328P00455000,30,1.09
[09:49:53.811441] trade,S,2,AAPL  130328C00470000,4.75
[09:49:53.811447] trade,B,95,AAPL,468.69
--
[09:50:31.241441] T,AAPL  130328P00430000,3,0.08
[09:50:31.385327] T,AAPL  130328P00455000,5,1.10
[09:50:31.385911] T,AAPL  130328P00455000,5,1.10
[09:50:31.458370] trade,B,2,AAPL  130328C00475000,2.80
[09:50:31.458373] trade,S,68,AAPL,468.46
--
[09:50:48.339322] T,AAPL  130328C00485000,8,0.92
[09:50:48.339341] T,AAPL  130328C00485000,1,0.92
[09:50:48.339357] T,AAPL  130328C00485000,9,0.92
[09:50:48.343785] trade,B,2,AAPL  130328C00465000,7.05
[09:50:48.343789] trade,S,118,AAPL,468.19
```

a match would be:

```
data A:  [09:50:31.458370] trade,B,2,AAPL  130328C00475000,2.80
data B:  [09:50:31.458370]
```

no match would be:

```
data A:  [09:49:53.811441] trade,S,2,AAPL  130328C00470000,4.75
data B:  #there is no timestamp from B which matches A
```

Comment: Could you show some sample data and point out what should match what? Another note: perhaps you should use a database for this.

Comment: Just a recommendation: Python 2.4 is pretty old (2004!), have you considered upgrading to a newer version?

Comment: Are there any guarantees you can make about the data?  Is it sorted, formatted, etc?

Comment: Janne, I provided some sample data from each file.  Also, I am not too familiar with databases.  I am very new to programming, but my job is requiring me to learn python.

Comment: A. Rodas, I asked my employer about upgrading their version of Python, but currently our server's OS only supports 2.4

Comment: Frankie, each new line in the "A" file is a subsequent timestamp, so it is sorted by time.  B is also sorted by time

Comment: What about duplication?  Could multiple subsequent lines in A have the same time stamp?  What about in B?

Comment: each timestamp in A is unique from any other timestamp in A.  The same goes for B timestamps in B.  However, A and B will have some matching timestamps.

Comment: Sure.  I've provided an answer that I think should get you on the right track.  If you need more specific information, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Forget regular expressions.  You should just chew through each stream.  Advancing and sorting matches as you can.  Some pseudo code:

```
Using Streams A and B, and Objects Match and NoMatch
FETCH next Line of A into LineA
FETCH next Line of B into LineB
WHILE Neither stream is at end of file:
    WHILE TimeStamp in LineA < TimeStamp in LineB:
        ADD LineA to NoMatch
        FETCH next Line of A into LineA
    WHILE TimeStamp in LineA = TimeStamp in LineB:
        Add (LineA, LineB) to Match
        FETCH next Line of A into LineA
    FETCH next Line of B into LineB
WHILE A is not at End of File
    ADD LineA to NoMatch
    FETCH next Line of A into LineA
```

This will handle repeats in A, but not in B.  To handle repeats in B, you have to maintain memory of past lines:

```
Using Streams A and B, and Objects Match, NoMatch and Temp
FETCH next Line of A into LineA
FETCH next Line of B into LineB
WHILE Neither stream is at end of file:
    CLEAR Temp
    WHILE TimeStamp in LineA < TimeStamp in LineB:
        ADD LineA to NoMatch
        FETCH next Line of A into LineA
    WHILE TimeStamp in LineA = TimeStamp in LineB:
        ADD (LineA, LineB) to Match
        ADD LineA to Temp
        SET Temp Timestamp to LineA Timestamp
        FETCH next Line of A into LineA
    FETCH next Line of B into LineB
    WHILE TimeStamp in LineB = Temp TimeStamp:
        FOR Line IN Temp:
            ADD (Line, LineB) TO Match
        FETCH next Line of B into LineB 
WHILE A is not at End of File
    ADD LineA to NoMatch
    FETCH next Line of A into LineA
```

EDIT:  I was ambiguous about how to determine EOF.  Let us presume that reading after EOF returns and empty string (as it does in python).  Implementation works more like this:

```
Using Streams A and B, and Objects Match, NoMatch and Temp
FETCH next Line of A into LineA
FETCH next Line of B into LineB
WHILE Neither LineA nor LineB is an Empty String:
    CLEAR Temp
    WHILE LineA is not an Empty String, AND TimeStamp in LineA < TimeStamp in LineB:
        ADD LineA to NoMatch
        FETCH next Line of A into LineA
    WHILE LineA is not an Empty String, AND TimeStamp in LineA = TimeStamp in LineB:
        ADD (LineA, LineB) to Match
        ADD LineA to Temp
        SET Temp Timestamp to LineA Timestamp
        FETCH next Line of A into LineA
    FETCH next Line of B into LineB
    WHILE LineB is not an Empty String, AND TimeStamp in LineB = Temp TimeStamp:
        FOR Line IN Temp:
            ADD (Line, LineB) TO Match
        FETCH next Line of B into LineB 

//At this point, Either LineA is empty (meaning there are no more strings to match),
//or LineB is empty (meaning there are no more matches to find).  If the first is true,
//This loop will be skipped.  Otherwise, this loop will put what's left of A into the 
//Not Matched Object.
WHILE  LineA is not an Empty String:
    ADD LineA to NoMatch
    FETCH next Line of A into LineA
```

Comment: thank you very much, Frankie!  I will have to try your solution tomorrow and I'll give you feedback.  thanks again

Comment: If this works for you, please accept the answer.  Beware, though:  This implementation does not handle empty lines in the file well.